# Convergence in norm

Tags: analysis, lebesgue-integral

If {$f_k $} is a sequence of Lebesgue integrable functions, then {$f_k$} is said to "converge in norm" to an integrable function $f$ if $\int | f_k - f | $ converges to zero . Can someone explain to me the concept behind convergence in norm ?

Comment: The $\ell^1$ norm is $\int |f|$.  So, $f_k\to f$ with convergence in the norm means $\int |f_k-f|\to 0$.

Comment: Do you know what a norm is?

Comment: Not much but it's a function that assigns length to vectors in vector spaces. But here I can't see the concept of length of any use.